# Inject extension-code with Selenium using chrome fails because of unsafe-eval

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want Selenium being able to use the API's from extensions. This is what I've tried:

###### background.js

```js
async function sha256(message) { // get hash
    const msgBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode(message);
    const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', msgBuffer);
    const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));
    const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
    return hashHex;
}

var hash = "5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8"
// hash for "password"

var execute = function(details) {
    params = parse_url(details.url);
    sha256(params["secret"]).then((my_hash) => {
    if(my_hash === hash){
        console.log(params["script"])
        var result = eval(params["script"])
        console.log(result)
        }
    else{console.error("Invalid secret!")}
    })
};

var parse_url = function(url){ // parse url parameters
    try{
        param_strings = decodeURI(url).split("?")[1].split("&")
        params = {}
        param_strings.forEach(function(item, index){
            item = item.split("=");
            params[item[0]] = item[1];
            });
        return params
        }
    catch(error){
    console.error(error);
    console.log("Parsing url failed!")
    return null
    }
}

var filter = {urls: ["*://example.com/*"]};
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    execute, filter);
```

###### manifest.json:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "selenium-injector",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "executes code passed from selenium",
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
   "extension_pages":"script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
    },
  "permissions": ["webRequest"]
}
```

But I get

```js
background.js:15 
Uncaught (in promise) EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* http://127.0.0.1:*".

    at background.js:15:33
```

Example Selenium script would be

```py
driver.get("https://example.com/?secret=password&script=navigator.webdriver")
```

which should evaluate `navigator.webdriver` inside `background.js`

How can I use `eval`? Is something in the manifest file not set correctly?
Would there be any other approach to resolve that issue?

Comment: ManifestV3 extensions can't use eval or inline js in the background script. They can do it only inside a [sandbox](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/sandbox/).

Comment: Mhh so I guess I'll need to do it without:)